# Different results when using requests and aiohttp

Tags: http

I'm trying to send requests to steem through purchased proxies. When using requests my ip is eventually banned, then I decided to use aiohttp and everything got better. What could this be and how to solve it?

```
async def test():
    for i in range(10):
        if i != 8 and i != 0:
            header = {'User-Agent':ua.random}
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=header) as session:
                proxy = 'http://login:pass@ip:pass'
                response = await session.get("https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Slate%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29/render/?query=&start=20&count=10&country=RU&language=english&currency=5", proxy=proxy)
                print('proxy ', response.status)
        else:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                response = await session.get("https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Slate%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29/render/?query=&start=20&count=10&country=RU&language=english&currency=5") 
                print('me ', response.status)
asyncio.run(test())
#me 200
#proxy 200
#proxy 200
#proxy 200
#proxy 429
#proxy 429
#proxy 429
#proxy 429
#me 200
#proxy 429
```

```
for i in range(10):
    if i != 8 and i != 0:
        proxy = {'http' : 'http://login:password@ip:port'}
        req = requests.get("https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Slate%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29/render/?query=&start=20&count=10&country=RU&language=english&currency=5", proxies=proxy)
        print('proxy ', req.status_code)
    else:
        req = requests.get("https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Slate%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29/render/?query=&start=20&count=10&country=RU&language=english&currency=5")
        print('me ', req.status_code)
#me 200
#proxy 200
#proxy 200
#proxy 429
#proxy 429
#proxy 429
#proxy 429
#proxy 429
#me 429
#proxy 429
```

I've done several tests with different free and paid proxies, the result is the same